# How can I work with cfmail failto attribute?

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I've checked with the cfmail tag. But, if we use failto attribute. It doesn't work to me. So, what can I do? Could you please provide an exact answer to me?

Comment: What does not work? What did you do? What did you expect?

Comment: Using cfmail-failto attribute,  our sending mail if failure means, the notification will send to what you mentioned in a failto="xxx@gmail.com".But, it doesn't happen. I get no notifications from the mail.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler , He asking about in which scenario the failto attribute get working ? Actually he tried to understand the usage of that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

There are many variables at play here but we rely on failto to function for a high volume email system so I can confirm it works. The underlying thing that is happening is that it lets you specify the envelope FROM for the message (what the email server sees) separately from the header FROM (what the receiving user sees). Envelope from can be considered like the reply address on a physical envelope and the header FROM like an address on the letter inside the envelope. If failto is not included in the cfmail tag then they are one in the same.

If the failto is being ignored for some reason or a mail server chooses to ignore it then then the header From address (cfmail from attribute) should be getting the bounce.

If the From address is not getting a bounce then your email is likely just not going out. The message has to reach the mail server for the bounce to occur. If ColdFusion is just failing to reach the mail server then mail will end up in the undelivr folder in your CF instance Mail directory. If that is happening then go into your CF admin interface and ensure the mail server can connect. To retry a message you can just move from undelivr to spool directory.

None of the above an issue? Make sure that you can send an email through your mail server to the failto address you are trying to use, otherwise there is no point in putting that address in the failto attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting a return email for failures, it's probably because the target email's server isn't set up to return a notification of failed delivery.

See here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/ColdFusion/CFMail-How-do-I-know-if-email-is-bounced/td-p/2001466